# Происходит ошибка Access denied for user 'evdoon'@'localhost' to database 'redu' (1044) при подключении mysql бд к bitrix

Tags: mysql, битрикс24

Имя пользователя написано верно, пароль и имя бд тоже, у пользователя все привилегии есть, но почему-то вылазит ошибка:

```
[mysqli_sql_exception] 
Access denied for user 'evdoon'@'localhost' to database 'redu' (1044)
C:\OSPanel\domains\localhost\bitrix\modules\main\lib\db\mysqliconnection.php:83
#0: mysqli->real_connect
     C:\OSPanel\domains\localhost\bitrix\modules\main\lib\db\mysqliconnection.php:83
#1: Bitrix\Main\DB\MysqliConnection->connectInternal
    C:\OSPanel\domains\localhost\bitrix\modules\main\lib\data\connection.php:53
#2: Bitrix\Main\Data\Connection->getResource
    C:\OSPanel\domains\localhost\bitrix\modules\main\lib\db\mysqlisqlhelper.php:21
#3: Bitrix\Main\DB\MysqliSqlHelper->forSql
    C:\OSPanel\domains\localhost\bitrix\modules\main\lib\config\option.php:206
#4: Bitrix\Main\Config\Option::load
    C:\OSPanel\domains\localhost\bitrix\modules\main\lib\config\option.php:83
#5: Bitrix\Main\Config\Option::getRealValue
    C:\OSPanel\domains\localhost\bitrix\modules\main\lib\config\option.php:32
#6: Bitrix\Main\Config\Option::get
    C:\OSPanel\domains\localhost\bitrix\modules\main\lib\httprequest.php:420
#7: Bitrix\Main\HttpRequest->prepareCookie
    C:\OSPanel\domains\localhost\bitrix\modules\main\lib\httprequest.php:77
#8: Bitrix\Main\HttpRequest->__construct
    C:\OSPanel\domains\localhost\bitrix\modules\main\lib\httpapplication.php:44
#9: Bitrix\Main\HttpApplication->initializeContext
    C:\OSPanel\domains\localhost\bitrix\modules\main\lib\application.php:135
#10: Bitrix\Main\Application->initializeExtendedKernel
    C:\OSPanel\domains\localhost\bitrix\modules\main\include.php:23
#11: require_once(string)
    C:\OSPanel\domains\localhost\bitrix\modules\main\include\prolog_before.php:19
#12: require_once(string)
    C:\OSPanel\domains\localhost\bitrix\modules\main\include\prolog.php:10
#13: require_once(string)
    C:\OSPanel\domains\localhost\bitrix\header.php:1
#14: require(string)
    C:\OSPanel\domains\localhost\index.php:2
----------
```

Уже всё просмотрел, localhost на 127.0.0.1 менял, но ничего не помогает. При чём, когда подключаюсь к бд через root всё работает. Надеюсь здесь сможете помочь, спасибо заранее!

Comment: Значит, реально недостаточно привилегий. Грузим CLI, подключаемся к MySQL от имени `'evdoon'@'localhost';` и смотрим `SELECT USER(), CURRENT_USER(), CURRENT_ROLE();` и `SHOW GRANTS;`.